# Proof of the union of two non mutual exclusive events

Tags: probability

I would know the proof of the union of two non mutual exclusive events. I know that two mutual exclusive events has the union defined like: $P(A\cup B) = P(A)+P(B)$ if $A\cap B = \varnothing  $
Can someone give me the proof that $P(A\cup B) = P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$

Thank you so much

Comment: Hint: 

First, draw the Venn diagram of two sets $A,B$ intersecting and try to write out the union as a disjoint union.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As 3 following sets $A \setminus B, A \cap B, B \setminus A$ are mutually exclusive, then you can use first formula to them:
$$P(A \cup B)=P \left( (A \setminus B ) \cup (A \cap B) \cup (B \setminus A)  \right) = P(A \setminus B) + P(A \cap B) + P(B \setminus A)$$
and then use $P(A)=P((A \setminus B) \cup (A \cap B))= P(A \setminus B)+P(A \cap B)$. Same for $P(B)$.

Comment: thx, following your idea: $P(A-B)=P(A)-P(A\cap B)$, $P(B-A)=P(B)-P(B\cap A)$ so I have: $P(A\cup B)=P(A)-P(A\cap B) + P(A\cap B) +P(B)-P(B\cap A) = P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$ where $P(A\cap B)=P(B\cap A)$ is this a good solution for you?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly for what I write my answer.

Comment: yes, I have refreshed the page and your answer is changed ;) thx! so, my last step, $P(A\cap B)= P(B\cap A)$ is correct?

Comment: Yes, of course. Truth table for "and" in help.

Comment: perfect! thx so much, I quote you like best answer.

Comment: Welcome. Thanks for estimation.

Answer (score 0):

One axiom of probability says "If A and B are disjoint, then $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)$."

Now $A\cup B = A \cup (B\cap A^c)$. $A$ and $B\cap A^c$ are disjoint. Thus
$$P(A\cup B )= P(A)+P(B\cap A^c).$$

Similarly, $B= (B\cap A^c) \cup (B\cap A)$. $B\cap A^c$ and $B\cap A$ are disjoint, which means
$$P(B\cap A^c)+P(B\cap A)=P(B).$$
Adding these two equations completes the proof.